# Creating a labeled column based on matches in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have Table1 with Items

```
ColumnA
Apple
Pear
```

I have Table2 with Items

```
ColumnB
Banana
Apple
Pear
```

It would like to create an output that has the following:

```
ColumnB Matched
Banana  0
Apple   1
Pear    1
```

I am attempting this by using the query

```
SELECT ColumnB
  FROM Table2 WHERE 
  ColumnB IN (SELECT ColumnA FROM Table1)
```

However, this only shows me the items I am interested in labeling but does not create a labeled column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a left join and testing for the existence of a joined value. Non-matching records will have null values for the joined table fields.

```
SELECT 
    ColumnB,
    Matched = CASE WHEN A.ColumnA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM
    Table2 A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 B ON B.ColumnB=A.ColumnA
```

Comment: The output this gives me only displays the matched apple and pear, but not the unmatched banana.  Perhaps I am missing something

Comment: It should be `Table2 B LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 A` i.e. swap tables around.